# From an R-prop-table to JSON: Headers are not included

Tags: json, r

I have the following table attained through `prop.table(table(test$Survived, test$Category), 2)` :

[image]

I'm using the `rjson`and entered into R-Studio:

```
titanicJSON <- toJSON(myTable)
```

However, this output looks like this:

```
[0.366666666666667,0.633333333333333,0.40625,0.59375,0.244444444444444,0.755555555555556,0.87719298245614,0.12280701754386,0.277777777777778,0.722222222222222,0.831081081081081,0.168918918918919,0.166666666666667,0.833333333333333,0.785046728971963,0.214953271028037,0.3125,0.6875,0.789473684210526,0.210526315789474,0.111111111111111,0.888888888888889,0.866666666666667,0.133333333333333,0,1,0.866666666666667,0.133333333333333,1,0,0,1]
```

How is it possible to have a JSON like this:

```
[{
    "0-9f": {
        "0": 0.366666666666667,
        "1": 0.633333333333333
    }
}, {
    "0-9m": {
        "0": 0.40625,
        "1": 0.59375
    }
}]
```

Comment: try `toJSON(as.data.frame(myTable))`

Comment: Wow, that's sth I can work with :) Thx a lot.